# DATE php and mysql unique

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Ok, my problem is very weird
I have this code in php passing three variables day month and year

```
$MONTH=$_POST['day']; 
$DAY=$_POST['month']; 
$YEAR=$_POST['year'];
$newdate="$YEAR/$DAY/$MONTH";
$DATEOFBITH=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($newdate));
```

the output of $newdate:
1967/1/1

looks good but when I look at the mysql it shows zeros
however if I write the code like below. and insert it to mysql it works!

```
$newdate="1986/1/1";
$DATEOFBITH=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($newdate));
```

I tried everything still not get it!

if also did comparison

```
$MONTH=$_POST['day']; 
$DAY=$_POST['month']; 
$YEAR=$_POST['year'];
$olddate="$YEAR/$DAY/$MONTH";
$newdate="1986/1/1";
if($newdate==$olddate){
echo "the same";
}
```

and it output:
the same

so, what is the problem?
when I use the POST, it does not work for mysql
but if I enter the date manually it works fine!

I tried trim/(string) none works :(

Comment: What is the value of `$DATEOFBITH`? I suspect it isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$newdate="$YEAR/$DAY/$MONTH";
```

To:

```
$newdate=$YEAR.'-'.$MONTH.'-'.$DAY;
```

Basically, you need to use a SQL standard date format to make sure PHP does not "guess" the format.